# Simple form wont post on wamp server

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a simple form that when I submit, redirects back to homepic.php (includes). I'm using wamp server on localhost. Does that have anything to do with it? The form information will be emailed to the recipient, which I haven't coded yet. Here's the code:

```
<?php
$field_name = $field_email = $field_message = "";
$nameError = $emailError = $messageError = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if (empty($_POST["cf_name"])) {
    $nameError = "Name is required";}
    else{$field_name = test_input($_POST['cf_name']);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$field_name)) {
      $nameError = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["cf_email"])) {
    $emailError = "Email is required";}
    else{$field_email = test_input($_POST['cf_email']);
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$field_email)) {
      $emailError = "Invalid email format";
    }}
    if (empty($_POST["cf_message"])) {
    $messageError = "Message is required";}
    else{$field_message = test_input($_POST['cf_message']);}

}
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
    Your name<br />
    <input type="text" name="cf_name" value="<?php echo $field_name;?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameError;?></span><br />
    Your e-mail<br />
    <input type="text" name="cf_email" value="<?php echo $field_email;?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailError;?></span><br />
    Message<br />
    <textarea name="cf_message" value="<?php echo $field_message;?>"></textarea>
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $messageError;?></span><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Here's my index navigation:

```
<div class="main">
    <?php switch ($_GET['page']) {
    case 'home':
    include ('homepic.php');
    break;
    case 'about':
    include ('about.php');
    break;
    case 'contact':
    include ('contact_form.php');
    break;
    case 'newwork':
    include ('ainewwork.php');
    break;
    case 'nature':
    include ('nature.php');
    break;
    case 'structures':
    include ('structures.php');
    break;
    case 'other':
    include ('other.php');
    break;
    default:
    include ('homepic.php');
    break;

    }              
    ?>
```

here's my nav code:

```
<nav>

     <ul id="menu">                              
        <li class="left"><a href="index.php?page=home">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=about">about</a></li>
        <li class="top"><a href="#">portfolios</a>
            <ul class="item"><li ><a href="index.php?page=newwork">new work</a></li>          

            <li ><a href="index.php?page=nature">nature</a></li>

            <li ><a href="index.php?page=structures">structures</a></li>               

            <li ><a href="index.php?page=other">other</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="right"><a href="index.php?page=contact">contact</a></li>                 
       </ul>                
      </nav>
```

Comment: I dont see where $_GET['page'] is coming from (you will need to post it back, and use that if you want the include after submit). 
It looks like you're hitting the default switch (which you have as homepic.php) 

Also, there is no need for htmlspecialchars in htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

Comment: added nav code. So it's because I'm using this type of navigation. How do I code the form so it posts back to itself in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your switch code to allow for GET/POST variable. You can define that var dependent on what you're doing.

```
 <?php switch ($_REQUEST['page']) {
    case 'home':
    include ('homepic.php');
    break;
    case 'about':
    include ('about.php');
    break;
    case 'contact':
    include ('contact_form.php');
    break;
    case 'newwork':
    include ('ainewwork.php');
    break;
    case 'nature':
    include ('nature.php');
    break;
    case 'structures':
    include ('structures.php');
    break;
    case 'other':
    include ('other.php');
    break;
    default:
    include ('homepic.php');
    break;

    }              
    ?>
```

Then inside your form, you can maintain the variable like this.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
    Your name<br />
    <input type="text" name="cf_name" value="<?php echo $field_name;?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameError;?></span><br />
    Your e-mail<br />
    <input type="text" name="cf_email" value="<?php echo $field_email;?>">
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailError;?></span><br />
    Message<br />
    <textarea name="cf_message" value="<?php echo $field_message;?>"></textarea>
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $messageError;?></span><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $_GET['page']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Comment: The code now works if there are blank fields and I get the fields are required messages, but if I enter incorrect information, it redirects to the homepic page again.

Comment: You will need to write some code to handle errors if there are any before including the page.

Comment: funny thing...I changed all gets to requests and now its fine. Clear button doesnt work now once there are error messages but I can probably use javascript to clear the entire form when clear is pressed.

Comment: Having another issue. The following function clears the span error messages but doesn't clear the input text:

Comment: <script>
$( "#clear" ).click(function() {
$( "span.error" ).empty();
});
$('#clear').click(function(){
        $('#myForm')[0].reset();
  });
</script>